# How to use a custom component to the tab bar navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need to use the Tab navigator but need to customize its tab bar. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: screen shot 2017-09-16 at 6 09 48 pm]

The middle button is not a screen in the tab bar. It's a custom button which opens a floating menu. Now I have already created this component but unable to attach it to my tab bar. All I want to do is to navigate to screens through this tab bar.

The app's code looks like this:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3' }}>
  <MainTabNavigator /> // The tabbar created from react-navigation
  <TabBar navigation={tabNavigation} /> // My custom tabbar
</View>
```

I tried to use the `NavigationActions` navigate function. It didn't work. I tried to pass the `navigation` props from a tab screen to my redux store, pass it back to my custom tab bar and used it's navigating function. The function gets passed but nothing happens. Yes, the last thing I did is a bit stupid. Can anyone please help me fix this?

Comment: Why don't you just build your own tabnavigator. It's a pretty trivial component. That's how I solved it.